# Properties of log map on matrices in $SE(3)$

Tags: matrices, logarithms, exponential-function, matrix-equations

I am learning about the log map on $SE(3)$ and I want to check my understanding of properties for use in solving an equation. Are the following true, for A, B, C as elements of $SE(3)$?

$$ \log(ABC) = \log A + \log B + \log C $$

$$ \log(e^{A}) = A $$

$$ \log(e^{At}) = At $$ for $t$ as a real number.

In particular I want to solve the equation

$$ e^{A_1t_1}e^{A_2t_2}e^{A_3t_3} = g $$ for scalars $t_1, t_2, t_3$ with $A_1, A_2, A_3, g$ in $SE(3)$. My plan is to use the log mapping to get an easier linear matrix equation to solve.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I assume that $A,B,C$ are rotations in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then the first equality is false. The second one is a non-sense because $e^A$ is not a rotation.

Comment: They represent twist motions, which consist of a rotation matrix, yes. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_theory#Twists_as_elements_of_a_Lie_algebra i.e. they are the matrices with the upper left 3x3 as the rotation matrix, the last column as translation axis, and the bottom row all zeros. Multiplied by thetas and take the exp map, they describe kinematics of a robot arm for example, and I was wondering if I can solve the algebraic equation a different way using log-map.